# jquery: clone after dropdown selected item

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, clone

I have a dropdown where the options are generated from the clone () function, for example:

```
    <select id="drop1">
        <option value="0">Select...</option>
        <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="Cats">Cats</option>
        <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
        <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
    </select>

    <select id="drop2">               
    </select>

        ...
<script>  
    $('#drop1').children().clone().appendTo('#drop2');
</script>
```

But what I want to know is how to clone items after dropdown selected item. Obviously in the event onchange() , for example, viewing the first dropdown:

```
   <select id="drop1">
        <option value="0">Select...</option>
        <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="Cats" selected>Cats</option> --> select item
        <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
        <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
    </select>
```

Clone result:

```
<select id="drop2">
    <option value="Dogs">Dogs</option>
    <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
</select>
```

My intention is to generate 2 fields of range (static data). I hope I can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDx6a/).

```
$('#drop1').change(function() {
   $('#drop2').empty();
   $("#drop1 option:selected").nextAll().clone().appendTo('#drop2'); 
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Try using .slice on children,

```
$('#drop1')
   .children()
   .slice($('#drop1')[0].selectedIndex + 1)
   .clone()
   .appendTo('#drop2');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dstCB/)

Edit: Onchange of `#drop1`

```
$('#drop1').change(function() {
    $('#drop2')
       .empty()
       .append(
              $(this).children().slice(this.selectedIndex + 1)
             .clone()
       );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dstCB/3/)

Comment: how I can generate cloning into the onchange event? please!